# Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=12; index=12 on samsung device 6.0.1 android version

Tags: java, android, android-viewgroup

Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=12; index=12 I encounter this bug only on samsung 6.0.1(android version) device.I didn't encounter this bug on any other android devices

stacktrace is below There is crash report on crashlytics but I couldn't reproduce error.

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1833)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchHoverEvent(ScrollView.java:1107)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
       at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:10074)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2839)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:3082)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2806)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10230)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5344)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5180)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4620)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7306)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7184)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7145)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7416)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)`

Comment: Java array indexes are 0 based. Someone in your code isn't taking that into account.

Comment: not enough info... make sure you add your question with enough information of what you were trying to do or code...

Comment: @TZHX error didn't seem in my code ,  error  occured android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent(ViewGroup.java:1833) it isnt my code

Comment: @swapyonubuntu this is all my information and error didnt seen in my code  Full stacktrace is added

Answer (score 1):

In the function `android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchHoverEvent`, there is an array. Let's call it `foo`.

`foo.length` is 12.

But someone has written, in line 1833, `foo[n]` for `n` being 12.

That's now allowed since, for an array of length 12. `n` must be between 0 and 11 inclusive. This, by the way, is an *extremely* common error to make.

I hope this is of some use. If anything it demonstrates how useful stack traces are.

Comment: i added all stacktrace

Comment: My answer still applies, did you have a look at the code at the line?

Comment: How to change Android's ViewGroup Code?

Comment: If it's really *their* bug (and that will only be the case 1% of the time so don't get to distracted), then you'll need to submit a bug report to them. In the meantime you can catch, and discard,  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I encounter this bug only on samsung 6.0.1(android version) device.I didn't encounter this bug on any other android devices